# Simple Maths Riddle 4

Tags: riddle, mathematics, limerick

> I cheer, I shout, I scream
>
> My growth is too extreme
>
> I'm way too vast
>
> Rates too fast
>
> Continuity can only be my dream.

What am I?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of Xhienne's answer to the first clue, how about:

> Because the gamma function is comprised of a factorial, which is represented by an exclamation point (!)

Answer (score 1):

Is it...

> The [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)?

```
I cheer, I shout, I scream
```

> Similarity between gamma and gamer, maybe?

```
My growth is too extreme
I'm way too vast
Rates too fast
```

> Similar to the factorial

```
Continuity can only be my dream.
```

> This is a discontinuous function